# How to close the window and quit the application when you press ESC key under OS X?

Tags: keyboard

On Windows it is something common to close a window by pressing `ESC` key. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to close the current Window and the application when I press `ESC`.

Currently the Preferences panel does not allow you to set a shortcut for `ESC`.

Use case: you open a file from another application inside a viewer or editor and you want to return to the initial application just by pressing `ESC` once.

Comment: Most Windows apps don't quit when you hit escape; they usually only close dialog boxes and pop-up panels. This is the same behavior on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

Downlod KeyRemap4Macbook
http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

See if you can't find a setting for escape, I'm not sure if there is one.
Remap it to Command + Q.

Answer (score 0):

You can press Command + W for closing the window and Command + Q to quit the applicaiton.

Like Open Word , open two different doc files and then if you wan to close only one file then just select that and press Command + w , only that file will be closed.

Hope this is the solutions for you.

Comment: I am already aware about common shortcuts, my question was if I can obtain the specified behavior in some way.